# Vagrant Provision AWS Issue

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, cookbook, berkshelf, berksfile

I am following the [Rails App Cookbook](https://github.com/gosuri/rails-app-cookbook) and am facing issue with step 6 which involves provisioning an AWS instance. I received the following [errors](https://gist.github.com/frmuses/1030bacf8ccdc87e2e01) as output.

As explained in the guide, upon observing the provisioning failure, I executed `vagrant up --provider=aws` and received the following [errors](https://gist.github.com/frmuses/721de88cda5fc7933809).

Here are the outputs of the [dependency file](https://gist.github.com/frmuses/16439df104a02164e557), [kernel gem file](https://gist.github.com/frmuses/b09dd00f2aa2646b3c46) and the [berks file](https://gist.github.com/frmuses/7720156bcefcb9f331b8) where the errors are observed.

Upon inspecting the errors and the berks file, I tried modifying line 11 to `version = "3.2.0"`, but that didn't make any difference as I can see the same [errors](https://gist.github.com/frmuses/f2d2b343fe2b7e4c840d).

Here is the output of the [Vagrantfile](https://gist.github.com/frmuses/a397459adfb5ae2336ab).

I investigated further and found the following issue being reported [Berkshelf Github](https://github.com/berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/issues/212) page. I tried the solution suggested - ensure that the Chef-DK directories are at the front of my $PATH by applying the following command `$ PATH=$HOME/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin:/opt/chefdk/bin:$PATH`

I observed the following [output](https://gist.github.com/frmuses/d569775d292f58851728) at my system.

Could someone please suggest what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. I was using the **vagrant-berkshelf** plugin. The correct plugin to be used is **berkshelf** alone. The issue was rectified after running the following commands:

```
vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-berkshelf
vagrant plugin install berkshelf
```